# Why is this partial template specialization failing?

Tags: c++, templates

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class> struct IsInteger;
template<class> struct IsInteger { using value = std::false_type; };
template<> struct IsInteger<int> { using value = std::true_type; };

int main()
{
   std::cout << std::boolalpha << 
   IsInteger<5>::value::value << '\n';
}
```

Above code results in an error saying

`Source.cpp(9,36): error C2974: 'IsInteger': invalid template argument for '<unnamed-symbol>', type expected`

`Source.cpp(9,50): error C2955: 'IsInteger': use of class template requires template argument list`

I don't understand why the compiler doesn't pick
`template<> struct IsInteger<int> { using value = std::true_type; };`
in this case. Why does it result in an error?

Comment: You seem to be confusing `int` with `5`.  `5` is not a type in C++.  You could do `IsInteger<decltype(5)>`.

Comment: `5` is a value. Your template expects a type. `IsInteger<int>` or any other type. It's possible to have a template take a non-type template parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use your trait as `IsInteger<int>` instead of `IsInteger<5>`.

Also, the idiomatic way to use `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` in cases like this is to inherit from them, instead of aliasing them as value:

```
template<class> struct IsInteger : std::false_type {};
template<> struct IsInteger<int> : std::true_type {};

int main()
{
   std::cout << std::boolalpha << IsInteger<int>::value << '\n';
}
```